# How to get `mail` on a CentOS 6 server (running postfix)

Tags: email, yum, postfix, mta, centos-6

On my old server, and most other devices I have run, there is a provided `mail` program.

On my new CentOS 6 server, running postfix as the MTA, I cannot send command-line email via `mail` - the tool is not there.

When running a `yum whatprovides mail` call, I get nothing helpful back:

```
$ yum whatprovides mail
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: centos.kiewel-online.ch
 * extras: centos.kiewel-online.ch
 * updates: centos.kiewel-online.ch
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                          | 4.2 MB     00:00
cr                                                       | 3.5 kB     00:00
cr/primary_db                                            | 3.9 MB     00:00
extras                                                   | 3.0 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                        | 1.9 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 3.5 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                       | 3.3 MB     00:00
Warning: 3.0.x versions of yum would erroneously match against filenames.
 You can use "*/mail" and/or "*bin/mail" to get that behaviour
No Matches found
```

How is user-to-user mail supposed to be sent on CentOS 6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In CentOS, this binary is provided by the `mailx` package:

```
yum install mailx
```

FYI, as the message at the bottom of your post indicates, you are using `whatprovides` incorrectly. Proper usage searching mirrors for a file called 'mail' would have been:

```
yum whatprovides */mail
```

Comment: I didn't realize I'd been running the `whatprovides` wrong - it's how you did it on older editions of `yum` :)

Comment: `yum whatprovides */mail` or `yum whatprovides *bin/mail`?